# Flutter OneSignal Notification Sound Not Working

Tags: flutter, notifications, android-notifications, onesignal

I use OneSignal to send notifications in my application I developed with Flutter. Notifications are coming. I also attached the audio file in accordance with the instructions on the site. But when the notification comes, the voice I added does not come. The phone's default notification sound is playing. Anyone have an idea about this?

res/raw/onesignal_default_sound.wav

res/xml/keep.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/onesignal_default_sound"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {
    "app_id": "APP_ID",
    "include_player_ids": ["PLAYER_ID"],
    "android_sound": "your_sound.wav",
    "android_channel_id": "CHANNEL_ID"
   }
```